# bash in Windows behaves differently than bash in Linux

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am using the following version of bash on Windows 10:

> GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)

I received a script from somebody who is running it on Linux. When running on Windows, I get a different result.

The script is `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
( . settings.sh ; . constants.js ) > output.js
```

`settings.sh`:

```
TEST_URL="https://myurl.com"
```

`constants.js`:

```
cat << EOF
export class Output {
}
Constants.Url = "$TEST_URL";
EOF
```

`output.js` on Linux looks as following:

```
export class Output {
}
Constants.Url = "https://myurl.com";
```

The script didn't run on Windows. I modified it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
( ./settings.sh ; ./constants.js ) > output.js
```

And on Windows:

```
export class Output {
}
Constants.Url = "";
```

Any idea how to write the script in order to get on Windows the same result as on Linux?

Comment: By bash on Windows, do you mean the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) (aka the Ubuntu app in the Windows store and similar) or Cygwin or Git Bash or something else?

Comment: That `test.sh` script shouldn't work *anywhere*; are you sure it is verbatim identical in both places? It doesn't have an extra `/` on line 3?

Comment: I do not reproduce your claimed Linux behaviour.  It is also incorrect behaviour.  The claimed Windows behaviour is the correct behaviour for the scripts presented.  I deduce that when you tested this on Linux, you already had `TEST_URL` in the interactive shell's environment.  Test _properly_ on Linux, and you will find that there is no difference in behaviour.  Your question should be how to make this behaviour what you want on _either_ platform.

Comment: @muru It is Git Bash

Comment: @MichaelHomer where do you see a '/'?

Comment: Thanks @JdeBP I didn't test on Linux. I will check

Comment: Line 3, byte 4.

Comment: Presumably it should be `. ./settings.sh`, to source that file,

Comment: @MichaelHomer you are right. I updated it in the question (what I included was after the modifications I have done for Windows, since it didn't run without them)

Comment: From the answer below, I see that I forgot to prepend '.' before './settings.sh'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> ( ./settings.sh ; ./constants.js )
> ```

This is running within a child process running the Bourne Again shell as a script interpreter.  It spawns a subshell, which in turn serially runs two scripts as child processes.

The first child script sets a shell variable.  It does not even *attempt* to export it from a shell variable to an environment variable.  But even if it *had*, that would not have worked.  The child process can only affect its own environment and that of its children.  It cannot affect its parent (sub-)shell, or its grandparent.  The second child script does not have the variable, and yields the output with the empty string.

The first script needs to be sourced, not run as a child process.

> ```
> ( . ./settings.sh ; ./constants.js )
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that I modified the linux script since it didn't run on windows. Updated the question, and your answer does what I needed to do...